# DNX Core 5 PagedList

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I can not find a reference to implemetar PagedList in DNX Core 5.0 or if any other library for paging. I would appreciate if someone can help me solve this kind of problem. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have published a pagination library, https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.Pagination that supports dnxcore50 and dnx451. It also has a similar PagedList class that is used in its demo web app.
There is a nuget for it on nuget.org

Comment: Hi ! 
I tried to install your library but it does not seem compatible with my verion of dnxcore  (= 5.0).

I have this error message :

The dependency cloudscribe.Web.Pagination 1.0.1-beta5 in project MapNHouse does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1. MapNHouse

The dependency cloudscribe.Web.Pagination 1.0.1-beta5 in project MapNHouse does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0. MapNHouse

Comment: hi, my project was updated for rc2 where dnx no longer exists. Best solution is for you to also update your projects to rc2, but you could just change to version 1.0.1-beta3 of my library which is the last one to support dnx